# whats the best datatype to store height?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

Pretty straight forward question, I want to store feet and inches in 1 column using a decimal, but I dont want it truncated like how the float type does.

Comment: Why don't you store it just in inches and present it as feet and inches in the UI?

Comment: decimal is for base-10 numbering. inches/feet are anything BUT base-10.

Comment: @MarcB Really you can't convert inches to feet and inches?

Comment: @blam: op did say "feet AND inches". `5.11` is somewhat ambiguous as a 'decimal'.

Comment: Definitely just store the total inches.  Pick one unit and store the numeric value of that unit.  Mixing units is never good for persisted data.  Simply remember to conceptually separate the data you're physically storing from the data you *have*.  Any data that can be *derived* from what you store (feet+inches can be derived from inches) is data that you have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic arithmetic, not computer science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store all your data in MKS (metric).  When presenting and storing convert the data into an international standard. and store it in a decimal type.

Thus if your tool to gather the data is in 6'2" format convert it into cm and save in your data table.  Then reverse this for display.

By saving in a standard format decimal cm. finding people with the same range of height is easier, where as if Ft and In are in separate columns ranges are really hard.

Comment: You don't have to go to metric to get base 10.  Inches is base 10 and can be stored in decimal.  For that matter feet is also base 10 and fractional feet can be converted to inches.

Comment: That is correct, it was more of a point to standardize data (MKS) in order to have a better starting point that will allow regionalization of data.
Such as my height of 6'2" could be stored as 6.16667 ft.
Just the English systems is dead.

Comment: In the US regionalization is feet / inches.  I google MKS and find nothing

Comment: For 99.9% of all Americans you are correct.
MKS Meter Kilogram Second, flash back to my old physics class.
http://lamar.colostate.edu/~hillger/laws/usmb.html
On 23 December 1975, President Gerald R. Ford signed the Metric Conversion Act of 1975, which finally gave official federal sanction for the U.S. to convert to using the metric system.
It is technically law but NOBODY changed over except the hard sciences. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units

Comment: And the OP is in the 99.9%.   Cheers

Comment: OP is looking to store inches, not meters. There's absolutely nothing wrong with keeping it simple and using a decimal field to store inches. 6'2" tall? That's 74 inches. 6'2-1/2"? Oh, that's 74.5 inches..... It can always be complicated (errr converted) later if internationalization is needed. I consider this to be a form of premature "optimization".

Answer (score 2):

The imperial unit system still used in Myanmar, Liberia and that one country in North America is unfortunately not very arithmetics-friendly. There is [no native data-type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) to handle the strange base12/base3/base1860 math for it.

You should really use the much more widely-used metric system and use a FLOAT or DECIMAL value representing meters.

However, when you really want to stay with the imperial system, you should store the value in inch and do the conversation to feet + inch on the GUI level.

Comment: The United States will consider moving to metric when Europe picks a language to speak.

Comment: The United States will consider moving to metric when it tires of being in an exclusive club with Libya and Burma.  I'd vote this silly comment down if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal lets you store an exact precision.

The question is if you want to store it in feet or inches.

If inches then: 
feet * 12 + inches

If feet then:
feet + (inches / 12)

If inches the conversion back

```
declare @inches dec(8,4)
declare @indesinfoot as dec(8,4);
set @indesinfoot = 12;
set @inches = (12*@indesinfoot) + 6.25;
print @inches;
SELECT cast(@inches/@indesinfoot as Int) as feet, 
       inches % @indesinfoot AS inches;
```

I would go with inches as you can get some rounding error with division but not with multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)  Data type

It lets you specify the precision you need for your specific needs, without truncating like FLOAT

Answer (score 0):

`NUMERIC()` or `DECIMAL()` will work for a single column answer, but you'll need to decide if you're storing feet or inches.  These fields use precise math and accurate storage.

If you must store feet and inches, you'll need to either define your own datatype (which is fairly complicated) or use two `NUMERIC()` or `DECIMAL()` fields.

Not that you'd ever run into precision problems with feet or inches with `FLOAT` when measuring something the size of a human being.  You'd be off by a hair.  Literally.

Answer (score 0):

Example procedure to convert the old English system to metric.  No error checking but it will give you an idea how to convert data as entered into data for storage.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ConvertHeight
    @Input varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @FT AS DECIMAL(18,10) = 0,
    @IN AS DECIMAL(18,10) = 0,
    @CM AS DECIMAL(18,10)

SELECT @FT = CAST(left(@Input,CHARINDEX('''',@Input,1) - 1) AS DECIMAL(18,10));
SELECT @IN = CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@Input,CHARINDEX('''',@Input,1) + 1,10),'"','')AS DECIMAL(18,10));
SET @CM = 2.54 * ((12 * @FT) + @IN);
    SELECT @CM
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to `store the data in single unit,either inches or in cm.`

Ideally give the user option to enter it in any format. Convert and show the user information in all the possible units like in feets and inches and cm.